# Trigger to get value from other table before insert

Tags: mysql

table structure

```
enclosure
----
id
time
label

accounting
---
id
enclosure_id
time
```

When `time` in `enclosure` table is updated the children in `accounting` should be updated too. Below trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `enclosure-after_update-time` AFTER UPDATE ON `enclosure`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.time <> OLD.time THEN
        UPDATE accounting SET time=NEW.time WHERE enclosure_id=NEW.id;
    END IF;
END
```

How to create a trigger on `accounting` on insert that gets `time` from `enclosure` and insert it into `accounting` ?

Comment: What problem are you having? It's basically the same, except you perform an `INSERT` statement instead of `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a before insert trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER `accounting_BEFORE_INSERT` 
BEFORE  INSERT ON `accounting`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

        SET NEW.time  = (SELECT time FROM enclosure WHERE id = NEW.enclosure_id ORDER BY tome DESC LIMIT 1);

END
```